# How do I fix this ValueError about Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_12: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2?

Tags: python, model, lstm, prediction, conv-neural-network

I got this error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_12: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
On line:
`history = model.fit(features_1, truth_1)`

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
history = model.fit(features_1, truth_1)
scores = model.evaluate(features_2, truth_2, verbose=0)
ypred = model.predict(features_2)
```

the shape of my variables are indicated below:
features_1 is (62276, 6)
features_2 is (62276, 6)
truth_1 is (62276, 1)
truth_2 is (62276, 1)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to reshape `features_1` or `truth_1` to include your batch size. For example, for features_1 the shape could be [1, 62276, 6].

Comment: Do I do this for all (features_1, features_2, truth_1, truth_2) or just 1. I tried with making just features_1 shape [1, 62276, 6] and I got the error message "Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 62276 target samples"

Comment: Trying doing all, because the error is will most probably occur for `scores` because they all have the same shape (mostly). Also, try reshaping to (seq_len, batch, input_size), which is the proper input shape